# If $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, strictly increasing with $f(x(y),y)=0$ for unique $x(y)$ for each $y$

Tags: functions, transformation

A claim:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, $f(x,y)$, strictly increasing in each of its arguments, with $f(x(y),y)=0$ for a unique $x(y)$ for each $y$, then $f$ must be a transformation of the function $x-x(y)$.

I know this is a stretch, and probably not true, but I need a result similar to this to solve another related problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442421/prove-that-a-continuous-succsim-is-quasilinear).

Truthfully, I am having a difficult time picturing what the condition "*$f(x(y),y)=0$ for a unique $x(y)$ for each $y$*" means for the function $f$.

Are there any implications of this condition for the function $f$ as defined? Is my claim true?

Comment: What do you mean by calling a function of two variables "strictly increasing"? $\Bbb R^2$ is not ordered by any standard convention.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I mean strictly increasing in each of its arguments. I.e. for $y_{0}$ fixed, $x<x' \implies f(x,y_{0})<f(x',y_{0})$, and the same argument for $y$. I have edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Any transformation of $x - y$ that is increasing in $x$ has to be decreasing in $y$, and vice versa. So a function that is increasing in both $x$ and $y$ cannot be a transformation of $x - y$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I apologize, $y$ was supposed to by $x(y)$ and I have edited the post. I think that the condition "$f(x(y),y)=0$ for a unique $x(y)$ for each $y$" along with the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing in its arguments will make $x(y)$ a decreasing function of $y$, so that $x-x(y)$ is increasing in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we already know that $f$ is strictly increasing in $x$, for a fixed $y$, there can be at most one $x$ for which $f(x, y)$ takes on any given value. So all that the $f(x(y), y) = 0$ condition adds is a requirement for all $y$, there exists an $x$ for which $f(x, y) = 0$.

Now consider $f(x, y) = x^3 + y$. This satisfies both conditions, so your claim is that $f(x, y) = F(x + \sqrt[3]y)$ for some $F$. But letting $y = 0$ gives $F(x) = x^3$ for all $x$. So we would have $x^3 + y = \left (x + \sqrt[3]y \right)^3$, which is false.